# Chess notation does not show figurine font

Tags: tex4ht, chess, skak

I am new to LaTeX/`skak`.
I use `htlatex` to generate a small ebook html.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ps,mover]{skak}

\title{test1\\Test}
\author{Asim}

\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt

\maketitle


\newgame
\mainline{1. d4 d5} \mainline{2. c4 Nf6 }


\end{document}
```

But the resultant notation shows up as an english letter  'N' instead of the figurine notation.
What wrong am I doing?

I have attached the log file (when I run `htlatex`), resultant `.mobi` file and the locations where I have Figurine fonts:
https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B5UN6Nh9m6BjZmxPNjV5NHhGcU0/edit

Appreciate if somebody could help, since I have tried everything that I could.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The tex4ht documentation has quite a bit about enabling different fonts.  Which methods there have you tried?

Comment: Which version of skak are you using? I tested now with skak 1.4 and MacTex and the font shows the pieces not the letters.

Comment: Try adding \usepackage{chess-workshop-symbols}

Comment: Thanks Andrew/Pouya. I noticed that with my original .tex pasted above, the .dvi file actually shows the figurine notation! I use Calibre to generate the .mobi file and the final .mobi file shows plain font instead of Figurine. What does this mean?

Comment: Noticed that immediately after the htlatex command, the console shows '--- warning --- Couldn't find font `SkakNew-FigurineBold.htf' (char codes: 32--121)'. Although the .dvi still shows with correct figurine font. I have skak version: (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/skak/skak.sty
Package: skak 2008/10/09 v1.5 Chess typesetting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide file `SkakNew-FigurineBold.htf`. This is virtual hypertext font, is used by `tex4ht` to convert characters from font encoding to `xml` encoding.

This file should look like this:

```
SkakNew-FigurineBold 32 121
'' ''     32
'!' ''     33
'&#x201D;' ''     34
'#' ''  35
'$' ''  36
'%' ''  37
'&#x0026;' ''  38
'&#x2019;' ''     39
'&#x0028;' ''  40
'&#x0029;' ''  41
'*' ''  42
'+' ''  43
',' ''  44
'-' ''  45
'.' ''  46
'/' ''     47
'0' ''  48
'1' ''  49
'2' ''  50
'3' ''  51
'4' ''  52
'5' ''  53
'6' ''  54
'7' ''  55
'8' ''  56
'9' ''  57
':' ''  58
';' ''  59
'&#x00A1;' ''     60
'=' ''  61
'&#x00BF;' ''     62
'?' ''  63
'@' ''  64
'A' ''  65
'&#9815;' '1'  66
'C' ''  67
'D' ''  68
'E' ''  69
'F' ''  70
'G' ''  71
'H' ''  72
'I' ''  73
'J' ''  74
'&#9812;' '1'  75
'L' ''  76
'M' ''  77
'&#x2658;' '1'  78
'O' ''  79
'P' ''  80
'&#9813;' '1'  81
'&#9814;' '1'  82
'S' ''  83
'T' ''  84
'U' ''  85
'V' ''  86
'W' ''  87
'X' ''  88
'Y' ''  89
'Z' ''  90
'&#x005B;' ''  91
'&#x201C;' ''     92
'&#x005D;' ''  93
'&#x02C6;' ''     94
'&#x02D9;' ''     95
'&#x2018;' ''     96
'a' ''  97
'b' ''  98
'c' ''  99
'd' ''  100
'e' ''  101
'f' ''  102
'g' ''  103
'h' ''  104
'i' ''  105
'j' ''  106
'k' ''  107
'l' ''  108
'm' ''  109
'n' ''  110
'o' ''  111
'p' ''  112
'q' ''  113
'r' ''  114
's' ''  115
't' ''  116
'u' ''  117
'v' ''  118
'w' ''  119
'x' ''  120
'y' ''  121
SkakNew-FigurineBold 32 121
```

Important lines for you are

```
'&#9815;' '1'  66
'&#9812;' '1'  75
'&#x2658;' '1'  78
'&#9813;' '1'  81
'&#9814;' '1'  82
```

these lines means that characters B, N, P, Q and R are converted as `xml` entities for unicode representation of chess characters. Number `1` in second column means, that these characters will be converted to images. This is needed in your case, because in ebooks you don't have much control about fonts. Particularly older versions of `kindle` doesn't support chess unicode characters, so you should insert them as images. You also should create custom config file for `tex4ht` conversion scripts, because by default, images are suited for computer screen with lower resolution, but `e-ink` devices have resolution about 167 ppi. For more info about this, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43801/2891). If you want characters instead of images, just delete these `1` on these lines.

You should also create config file for `skak`, because if you try to print `chessboard`, instead of image, you will also get only some characters.

File `skak.4ht`

```
\NewConfigure{showboard}{2}
\let\oldshowboard\showboard
\Configure{showboard}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}
\renewcommand\showboard{\a:showboard\oldshowboard\b:showboard}
```

Some sample file `skak-sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ps,mover]{skak}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\newgame
\mainline{1. d4 d5} \mainline{2. c4 Nf6 }
\mainline{3.Ka1 Qa1 4.Ra1 Ba1 5.Na1 a1}
\showboard
\end{document}
```

Now with `htlatex skak-sample` you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I shall definitely try it. As a backup I plan to convert the dvi to PNG images and then insert them into html and prepare the eBook manually! *sigh*

Comment: It worked! T.H.A.N.K.S!