# using mathml in htlatex makes it lose the table p-width specification in generated html

Tags: tables, tex4ht, htlatex, mathml

It took me a while to find the cause of this. when giving `p{}` for table column width, and also using `mathml` option, then htlatex losses the width specs in the generated HTML table.

It is very simple to reproduce. Below is the .tex files and the commands, and the HTML output.

I need to use `mathml` since I am using mathjax in htlatex configuration to render the Latex math on the screen. Without using `mathml` then mathjax does not work. So this is a big problem because now all the tables I have where I specified width of columns are lost in the HTML version.

Minimal working latex file

```
\documentclass{article}%
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{3in}|p{1in}|p{1in}|}\hline
   blablablaaablabla&blablablaaablabla&blablablaaablabla
   \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This command works

```
htlatex index.tex "htm,p-width"
```

[image]

This command does *not* work

```
htlatex index.tex "htm,mathml,p-width"
```

[image]

The "p-width" option is important. See [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/tex4ht-and-tables/1909436) for reference on it. it was added by Eitan in 2004 to support column widths in HTML.

Again, I have to use mathml, and I also need to have tables of fixed width columns, or be able to specify the column width. Now I can't do both if I am to use MathJax with htlatx generated HTML.

Any one knows of a work around please?

TL 2012 debian package.

ps. I actually would rather not use Mathjax, but without it, the generated math using .png does not look as good, and I have not figured out how to make it look better. So, may be I should spend more time on this. If I can get htlatex to generated good math using .png images, then I do not have to use Mathjax, and do not have to use the `mathml` option and the problem will be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small attempt to make table width appear automatically in HTML file with `mathml`. I have used the header from [MathJax + HTML5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/convert-latex-to-mathjax-html/68962#68962) in the configuration file with rest of the macros.

**Sample TeX with Tables**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3in}|p{1in}|p{1in}|}\hline
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   $B (x) =-x ^ 2 + 60x-500$
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   &
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   $B (x) =-x ^ 2 $
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   &
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   $B (x) =500$
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\tabwidth{9in}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3in}|p{1in}|p{1in}|l|c|r|}\hline
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   $B (x) =-x ^ 2 + 60x-500$
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   &
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   &
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   blablablaaablabla
   &
   Test
   &
   Test
   & Test
   \\\hline
   a & b & c & a & b & c\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\tabwidth{7in}
\begin{tabular}{lcr lcr lcr}\hline
One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Configuration File (ht5mathjax-tbwd.cfg)**

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}

\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
                               content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
(http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
  .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

\catcode`\:11
\catcode`\@11

% Added to fix the opening and closing <p> tags
\Configure{HtmlPar}
  {\EndP\HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->%
<p \csname a:!P\endcsname
         class="no\ifHCond par\else indent\fi" \a:LRdir>}}
  {\EndP\HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->%
<p \csname a:!P\endcsname
        class="\ifdim \parindent=\z@ no\fi indent" \a:LRdir>}}
  {{\Tg</p>}}
  {{\Tg</p>}}%

{
  \def\x:Em{%
    \catcode`\p=12
    \catcode`\t=12
    \gdef\x:Em}
  \x:Em#1pt{#1}
}
\tmp:dim=10em
\edef\ten:Em#1.#2//{#1}
\edef\ten:Em{\expandafter\ten:Em \the\tmp:dim//}

\newdimen\tmp::dim
\newdimen\tmp:::dim
\def\tabwidth#1{\tmp::dim=#1}
\tmp::dim=5in

\def\paAignType{p}
\let\VBorder\empty   \let\AllColMargins\empty
\newcount\Tab:PCell
\newcount\Tab:PVoid
\newdimen\Tab:Wd
\newdimen\Tab::XWd
\newdimen\Tab:XWd

\Configure{halignTB}{%
   \@ifundefined{abc@Wdth-TBL-\TableNo}
     {}
     {\tmp::dim=\csname abc@Wdth-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname}%
   \Tab::XWd=\tmp::dim%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname abc@WdGZ-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname\relax\else%
       \advance\Tab::XWd by -\csname abc@WdGZ-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname%
       \divide\Tab::XWd by \csname abc@PVoid-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname%
   \fi%
   %
   \divide\tmp::dim by \ten:Em\relax
   \tmp::dim=10\tmp::dim
   \HCode{<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:\expandafter\x:Em \the\tmp::dim em" 
   }}{\HCode{>}\tmp::dim=5in}

\Configure{VBorder}
   {\let\VBorder\empty \let\AllColMargins\empty%
    \global\let\GROUPS\empty \HAssign\NewGroup = 0%
    \Tab:Wd=0pt\HAssign\Tab:PCell = 0\HAssign\Tab:PVoid = 0%
    \gHAdvance\Next:TableNo by 1 \global\let\TableNo=\Next:TableNo }
   {\xdef\VBorder{\VBorder\ifnum \NewGroup> 0 \HCode{\Hnewline</colgroup>}\fi}
    \HAssign\NewGroup = 0  \gdef\GROUPS{rules="groups"}}
   {\Advance:\NewGroup by 1
    \ifnum \NewGroup=1 \xdef\VBorder{\VBorder\HCode{\Hnewline<colgroup
        id="TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt g">}}\fi
    \@ifundefined{abc@TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt}{}
      {%
        \tmp:dim=\csname abc@TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt\endcsname%
        \divide\tmp:dim by \ten:Em\relax
        \tmp:dim=10\tmp:dim
      }%
      \ifx\paAignType\ch:class
        \gHAdvance\Tab:PCell by 1%
        \@ifundefined{abc@TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt}{}
          {\advance\Tab:Wd by \csname abc@TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt\endcsname}%
      \else
        \gHAdvance\Tab:PVoid by 1%
      \fi
    \xdef\VBorder{\VBorder\HCode{\Hnewline\space<col\Hnewline\space\space id="TBL-\TableNo
       -\ar:cnt"\Hnewline}
       \HColAlign\HCode{\Hnewline}
       \ifx\paAignType\ch:class
         \HCode{ width="\expandafter\x:Em \the\tmp:dim em"\Hnewline}
         \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
            \string\csname\space abc@TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt\string%
            \endcsname{\csname @testpach \ar:cnt\endcsname}}
       \else
         \@ifundefined{abc@WdLCR-TBL-\TableNo}
           {\HCode{ width="1*"\Hnewline}}
           {\HCode{ width="\csname abc@WdLCR-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname"\Hnewline}}%
       \fi
       \HCode{/>}}\xdef\AllColMargins{\AllColMargins1}}
   {\xdef\AllColMargins{\AllColMargins 0}}
\Configure{halignTD} {}{}
   {<}{\HCode{ style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;"}}
   {-}{\HCode{ style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;"}}
   {>}{\HCode{ style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:right;"}}
   {^}{\HCode{ style="vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap;"}}
   {=}{\HCode{ style="vertical-align:baseline; white-space:nowrap;"}}
   {|}{\HCode{ style="vertical-align:middle; white-space:nowrap;"}}
   {_}{\HCode{ style="vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap;"}}
   {p}{\HCode{ style="white-space:wrap; text-align:left;"}}%
   {m}{\HCode{ style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;"}}
   {b}{\HCode{ style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:baseline;"}}
   {}

\def\putVBorder{\expandafter\put:VBorder\VBorder</>!*?: }
\def\put:VBorder#1</#2>#3!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}\ifx\:temp\empty
     \VBorder%
     \def\:temp{#1}\ifx\:temp\empty \else\ifnum \NewGroup> 0\HCode{\Hnewline</colgroup>}\fi\fi
  \else  \def\:temp{\put:VBorder#3!*?: }\expandafter\:temp\fi
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
     \string\csname\space abc@TBL-\TableNo\string%
     \endcsname{\ar:cnt}}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
     \string\csname\space abc@PCell-TBL-\TableNo\string%
     \endcsname{\Tab:PCell}}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
     \string\csname\space abc@PVoid-TBL-\TableNo\string%
     \endcsname{\Tab:PVoid}}
  \expandafter\ifx\csname abc@PCell-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname\relax%
  \else%
     \expandafter\ifnum\csname abc@PVoid-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname=0%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
           \string\csname\space abc@Wdth-TBL-\TableNo\string%
           \endcsname{\the\Tab:Wd}}
     \fi%
     \expandafter\ifnum\csname abc@PVoid-TBL-\TableNo\endcsname>0%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
           \string\csname\space abc@WdGZ-TBL-\TableNo\string%
           \endcsname{\the\Tab:Wd}}
        \divide\Tab::XWd by \ten:Em\relax
        \Tab::XWd=10\Tab::XWd
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef%
           \string\csname\space abc@WdLCR-TBL-\TableNo\string%
           \endcsname{\expandafter\x:Em \the\Tab::XWd em}}%
     \fi%
  \fi%
}

\endinput
```

**Command Line**

```
htlatex <filename> ht5mathjax-tbwd
```

**Know Problem**

1. The cfg writes to `.aux` for calculating the width of the cell. So you need to run at least twice the `htlatex` command.
2. If a table contains only cells with `p{...}` value (for example in the first `tabular` of my example), then no need to provide `\tabwidth{...}` before `\begin{tabular}{...}`. The configuration file itself will calculate the width by adding the cell widths. If any of the cell contains `l,c,r`, the you need to set `\tabwidth{...}`, otherwise the cells will overlap when we view in browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nasser: You can also switch to `dvipng` from `convert` via `tex4ht.env` , which creates better quality images. For this please see the [answer to this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43772/latex-xhtml-with-tex4ht-bad-quality-images-of-equations).