# Increase equation resolution in TeX4ht using accessible images or typeset text

Tags: equations, tex4ht, html, resolution

When `TeX4ht` compiles my latex code it generates a png of my equation and includes this in the html file.  Until a better alternative for this comes along I am quite happy with this way of managing/presenting my equations.

This is a collaborative project and I am working with some very anti-latex and anti software people, so I generate html files that they can edit.  By ensuring complete compatibility between the html file and pdf generation everyone remains happy.  I would however prefer to have a higher resolution image that my collaborators can read without getting frustrated with the document quality.

Approaches I have investigated and been unsuccessful with:

1. An excellent explanation that I apologize for missing during my initial week spent trying to solve this issue here [LaTeX --> (X)HTML with tex4ht: bad quality images of equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43772/latex-xhtml-with-tex4ht-bad-quality-images-of-equations) uses a conversion of eps to svg.

Unfortunately eps are not file extensions that my collaborators can open, nor is it something they are willing or even capable to upgrade software to work with.  So This solution is not my preferred approach unless the final image type is not an eps.

I am sure I am not doing something quite right with the implementation of this as on our work computers I am left only with the eps file, no png or svg are created, and browser/editable integration of the eps is hit or miss.  If memory serves, the mentioned `convert` program is part of `imagemagick` which we do have installed, so I am at a loss why the svg or png creation is absent using the custom cfg file mentioned in the solution.  Maybe this should be the question itself which I believe is completely distinct albeit related to the question that this is currently marked as a duplicate for.

2. It might be neat to use a completely different approach maybe using http://latex2html5.com which honestly I haven't even been able to figure out how to compile their examples - but I feel it holds promise for the issue I described above if I can figure out what it is supposed to do and how to do it (unless this tool is the best option to solve my problem, this is a question for another day which I will post and edit this question to remove this aspect to prevent duplication).  One aspect of this approach that would interest me, is the appearance that this is not a picture, but formatted text...

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        \begin{equation}
            \text{C~=~}{\frac{a}{b}}
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43772/2891

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches described in the linked answer. Route
from eps to output formats is the default way `tex4ht` deals with
generated images. You shouldn't get `eps` images as final format, it
is always converted to something which can be displayed with a
browser.

another way is to use some `dvi` to image converter such as `dvipng`
or `dvisvgm`. To avoid need to modify the `.env` file, which was in depth described in the linked answer,  I will show
solution using [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht).

create a build file, named as `texfilename` + `.mk4` suffix:

```
Make:htlatex{}
Make:image("png$","dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -D151 --freetype -o     ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:image("svg$","dvisvgm -n -p ${page} -c 1.4,1.4 -s ${source} > ${output}")
```

this build file calls `htlatex` only once, as you don't use hyperlinks and references, which need more `htlatex` runs.

`Make:image` declaration are used depending on the used image output (which can be configured). for `png` output, `dvipng` is used, for `svg`, it is `dvisvgm`. you can set the image resolution with `-D` option for `dvipng` and `-c` option for `dvisvgm`, you need to try some values, which one will fit your text best.

for `png` output, compile with

```
make4ht filename
```

the result:

[image]

to compile to `svg`, you need to configure image output, for example with such config file., `hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

compile now with

```
make4ht -c hello filename
```

and the output:

[image]

you may need to read man pages for `dvipng` or `dvisvgm` and play with parameters to suit your needs

Comment: Is your second stage for the svg compilation dependent on the make4ht compile?  This is the step that in my question I am not sure what prerequisite program is required/why my system can't see it (in addressing the first part of your answer, I definitely don't get any files other than eps - so if possible I would like to fix that problem).

Comment: Actually I think the first stage question I could use some elaboration on is "Can make4ht be installed on a windows system with MikTex"?  I just realized that mk4ht and make4ht are not the same thing, Duh!

Comment: @EngBIRD detailed install instructions for Windows with TeXLive (but it should be similar with Miktex) are here: https://d800fotos.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/create-e-books-from-latex-tex-files-ebook-aus-latex-tex-dateien-erstellen/

Comment: How is make4ht converted to a recognized executable file?  I think the only thing different on the installation of miktex vs texlive is the absence of a texmf directory, but since it is easy to add a root to miktex, I believe these should be equivalent.  However, the make4ht file has no extension and windows can't recognize this as program to be run.  I have tried running this command line directive having set this up as an environment variable and an explicit file path to this file.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @EngBIRD you need to create a batch file in form of `texlua "C:\path\to\local\texmf\scripts\lua\make4ht\make4ht" %*` and place it somewhere in the pat, so it can be called from anywhere

Comment: @michal.h1 Sorry, I have tried every combination I can think of but I just don't understand texlua, or %*.  I don't have any files called texlua or tex.lua.  Looking at the contents of make4ht and all the .lua files in the directory, they all seem to be of the same coded format - not at all compatible for a batch file.  Should I start an independent question so I can provide more details about what I have tried?  Thanks.

Comment: @EngBIRD yes, it would be probably better to make new question, it would allow me to describe the installation process in more depth

Comment: Just a short note: The dvisvgm command-line option `-n` is an abbreviation for `--no-fonts`. So it's not necessary to add both options in the above mk4 example but you can omit one of them.

Comment: @michal.h21 I am now getting a svg file running the compile sequence with the custom cfg and mk4 files as posted in your solution.  When I open the result however the result is a broken link icon.  When I change \Configure{Picture}{.svg} for .png it with the addition of -D 720 option as described http://www.nongnu.org/dvipng/dvipng_4.html doesn't seem to have an effect but this article seems to corroborate that this attempt is not the approach to take:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114786/increase-image-quality-from-dvipng-without-increasing-image-size