# Convert to HTML with {arabtext} sections rendered as images

Tags: html, htlatex, ebook, arabtex

I'm just starting to investigate using latex to generate an ebook with arabic snippets embedded in it, and I'm using the following simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\begin{document}

Hello world

\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
السَلامُ عَليكم
\end{arabtext}

Goodbye World!

\end{document}
```

Here's the output with pdflatex:

[image: pdflatex output]

When I try converting to html, here is the garbled output:

[image: htlatex output]

Generated HTML source:

```
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >Hello world
                                                        <span 
class="xnsh-14"></span><span 
class="xnsh-14">J</span><!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >
<span 
class="xnsh-14"></span><span 
class="xnsh-14"></span><!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >
<span 
class="xnsh-14"></span><span 
class="xnsh-14"></span> <!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >
   <span 
class="xnsh-14"></span> <span 
class="xnsh-14"></span><span 
class="xnsh-14">C</span> <!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >
      <span 
class="xnsh-14"></span> <span 
class="xnsh-14"></span><span 
class="xnsh-14">@</span>
<!--l. 16--><p class="indent" >   Goodbye World!
```

What I want is to render the arabic as an image (that looks like the pdf-rendered version) and have that image in the html source. Something like:

```
<span>Hello world</span>
<img src="foo.png" />
<span>Goodbye World!</span>
```

What's the best way to tackle this issue? I'm completely new to latex but don't mind if the solution requires some programming for pre-processing on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite easy to produce images with content of any environment. Any TeX content can be converted to image with `\Picture+ ... \EndPicture` commands, so we only need to configure `arabtext` environment to use these commands. Save following code as `arab.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{arabtext}{\HCode{<div class="arabtext">}\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\Css{.arabtext{text-align:right;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This code will create `<div class="arabtext">` element and all content of the environment is converted to image. The image is then aligned to the right using CSS.

Compile with

```
htlatex filename arab
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful. The only issue I have is the image resolution seems to be very low, how can I get a higher resolution image generated from the \Picture+ command?

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43801/2891 for image resolution settings