# `make4ht`, `htlatex`: "cannot read log file" issue with minimal example

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I have a simple *.tex file for this question:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}

\section{Section One}
    Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
        \begin{equation}
            x + y = 3
        \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43772/latex-xhtml-with-tex4ht-bad-quality-images-of-equations) taught me how to fix image quality issues (for equations, etc.) that I was having when using `htlatex`. So, when I run:

`htlatex test_article.tex`,

I get nice HTML output.

---

Now I am interested in doing the same thing, except with `make4ht`, but I have some questions after reading the documentation:

1) Why is `htlatex()` command repeated twice in the filters example?

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
Make:htlatex()   <--- first time
Make:htlatex()   <--- second time?
Make:match("html$",process)
```

2) Image conversion: the documentation recommends a command like this:

```
Make:image("png$",
"dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
```

How will `${output}`, `${page}` and `${source}` be figured out? Is this automatic, or is this assuming that I have supplied these parameters somewhere? If the second, where should I supply these parameters?

---

So far, I have written the following in `test_article.mk4`:

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
Make:htlatex()
Make:htlatex()
Make:image("png$",
    "dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:match("html$",process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

I run the following command (`-n` for disable `tex4ht`):

`make4ht "test_article.tex" -n`

...but then get the following error:

```
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:28 kpathsea)
t4ht -p
  test_article.dvi
(a:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `test_article.lg'
Parse LG
Cannot read log file: test_article.lg
```

Hopefully, this error is related to some of my questions that I have asked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the `Make:htlatex` runs LaTeX once, it isn't the same as calling `htlatex` script which runs LaTeX three times. It is called three times because of crossreferences and links.

You can speed the compilation using `mode` variable, which can be passed as command line parameter. I usually define `draft` mode where `Make:htlatex` is called only once and then compile with

make4ht -m draft filename

sample build file with `mode` variable:

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex()
else
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
end
Make:image("png$",
"dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:match("html$",process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

2) these parameters are set automatically, the image conversion is driven by the `.lg` file. Images are stored in special `dvi` file with `.idv` extension, it is the `source` parameter. every image is on standalone page, so `page` is number of the current converted image, `output` is the image name.

3) don't use the `-n` option, it disables `tex4ht` conversion from `dvi` to `html`, which is clearly not something you want

Comment: Thank you so much for `make4ht`, and your answer! You're right, I don't want the `-n` option, I misread it as the option to disable tex4ht from processing the image files -- how do I do that disabling (or is it automatic with the `image` function)?

Comment: @user89 the image processing is disabled by `image` function automatically. `-n` option should be passed to `t4ht`, you can pass it using `mak4ht filename "" "" " -n"`, but you don't need it

Comment: Very nice! I also just posted another question, if you are able to answer it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286723/make4ht-increasing-font-size