# `make4ht`: increasing font size

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I have a simple *.tex file for this question:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}

\section{Section One}
    Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
        \begin{equation}
            x + y = 3
        \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Now, when I increase font size in the `\documentclass` command from `12pt` to `16pt`, I don't see a corresponding increase in font size in the output HTML.

Why is that?

Here is my build file:

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex()
else
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
end
Make:image("png$",
"dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:match("html$",process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

Comment: the `article` class doesn't have any font options larger than `12pt`, so that's not going to get you where you want to go.  you can try inserting `\Huge` at the beginning (after `\begin{document}`).  that will enlarge the text, but not titles or section headings, in the tex output.  i don't know whether it will carry over to the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't work even in `pdf` mode, standard `article` class doesn't support `16pt` option. You can use `scrartcl` but it will probably change appearance of your document. Anyway, here is a modified example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}

\section{Section One}
    Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
        \begin{equation}
            x + y = 3
        \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

this works in `pdf` mode, but `tex4ht` uses fixed `CSS` template by default, so the changed font size isn't used in the `html`. You can use custom config file and configure the font size through `css`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{font-size:1.3em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Note that it is better to use `em` dimensions in `css` instead of `pt. You can use the config file:

make4ht -c config.cfg filename.tex

the result:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, I found that the math was not well-sized as in your example. What might the difference in our cases be?

Comment: Figured out the difference! I was not using `\documentclass[fontsize=16pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}` (I figured I didn't need it because I didn't want pdf only change). However, it is good to have it because it makes the math bigger too.

Comment: @user89 yes, math has size depending on the original document size, so resizing is needed. You can also add `-D <resolution>` as `dvipng` parameter, if you don't want to modify the document